# Plane textures render as black box

Tags: ios, aframe

So, I used A-frame's "360 Image Gallery" example as a starting place to prototype a concept. Easy and perfect except...all of the plane primitives render as black squares (rather than rendering their material texture) in safari and chrome on ios.

Even if I view the provided example in safari desktop Version 16.5 the three image targets render as black squares, missing their material: https://aframe-gallery.glitch.me/

Oddly, in the example, all assets are declared in the same way, using the same crossdomain attributes, but the sky primitive texture renders while the plane textures do not.

In Brave and Chrome desktop, the textures load beautifully, leading me to think I'm not TOTALLY crazy.

I've tried a few different images, formats, entity configuration. I tried loading the images locally rather than via cdn. No luck.

Anyone have a hint what might be causing this? :D